# If $f(x)$ is continuous function and $f(2) = 10,$ Then $f(1.5)$ is

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined for $1 \leq x\leq 3$. If $f(x)$ takes rational values for all $x$
>
> and $f(2) = 10,$ Then $f(1.5)$ is

Attempt: $f(x)$ is continuous function and $1 \leq x \leq 3$ Then $f(x)$ has

maximum and minimum values in $ 1 \leq x \leq3 $

wan,t be able to go further from here, could some explain me, thanks

Comment: Hint: Check whether $5$ is even in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Thanks   Hagen von Eitzen I have edited it.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and takes at least two distinct rational values $r<r'$, then by the intermediate value theorem...

Comment: please explain me in detail  Clement C., thanks

Comment: If $f$ is not constant, it takes at least two rational values $r<r'$. But then, by the IVT, it also takes every value in between, some of them are irrational. This contradicts the assumption that $f$ only takes rational values.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is continuous in $[1,3]$, then $f([1,3])$ is a closed interval. Since $f(x)$ is rational for all $x\in[1,3]$, $f(x)$ must be a constant. Otherwise, $f([1,3])$ contains two rational values $r<r′$. Note $[r,r']$ contains an irrational number $s$. By IVT, there is $x\in[1,3]$ such that $f(x)=s$, which contradicts the assumption that f only takes rational values. Thus $f([1,3])$ is just a point. Note $f(2)=10$ and hence $f([1,3])=\{10\}$. Thus $f(1.5)=10$.

Comment: Nitpicking, but mentioning "intermediate value theorem" as the reason for which $f([1,2])$ is an interval would probably help the OP for future proofs.

Comment: @ClementC., you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find $f(1.5)$, since $f(5)$ doesn't exist given the domain of $f$.

$(1,3)$ is a continuous set and $f$ is continuous: hence the image set of f, $\mathcal{I}(f)$ must be continuous.

You also know that $10\in \mathcal{I}(f)$ (because of $f(2)$) and $\mathcal{I}(f) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ (because $f$ takes rational values).

There is only one subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is continous, contains $10$ and is included in $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: Does "continuous" with reference to sets here mean the same thing as "connected?"

Comment: Yes. My mathematical english sometimes lacks precision, I learned maths in french...